# Laravel 7 show correct user on modal (popup)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, alpine.js

all
I have an admin panel for my Laravel 7 application and I want to have a popup modal when I hit the edit button. this modal should show the correct user selected but it doesn't ist just showing the last user (user 10 because I have it paginated to 10 per page. I have a for each loop with all the user (paginated). I'm using alpine js to load the modal. Is there a way with javascript to pass the correct user through?

I have also tried using jquery creating a unique modal for each user but that didn't work either

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <tr class="text-white pt-2">
    <td class="text-center">{{ $user->id }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $user->firstName }} {{ $user->lastName }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ implode(', ', $user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray())}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <button @click="open = true"  ><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is my Modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.update', $user) }}" method="POST">
  @CSRF
  @method('put')  
<div class="modal pointer-events-none fixed w-full h-full top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center" x-show="open">
  <div class="modal-overlay absolute w-full h-full bg-gray-700 opacity-50"></div>

      <div class="modal-container bg-white w-5/12 mx-auto rounded shadow-lg z-50 overflow-y-auto bg-gray-900 text-white container px-5" @click.away="open = false">

        <div class="modal-close absolute top-0 right-0 cursor-pointer flex flex-col items-center mt-4 mr-4 text-white text-sm z-50" @click="open = false">
          <svg class="fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
            <path d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"></path>
          </svg>
          <span class="text-sm">(Esc)</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Add margin if you want to see some of the overlay behind the modal-->
        <div class="modal-content py-4 text-left px-6">
          <!--Title-->
          <div class="flex justify-between items-center pb-3">
            <p class="text-2xl font-bold">Edit User {{ $user->id}}</p>
            <div class="modal-close cursor-pointer z-50">
              <svg class="fill-current text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                <path d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>

            <!--Body-->
            <div class="flex justify-start">
              <div class="w-1/2">
                <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                  <p class="w-full text-sm">Name:</p>
                  <p class="w-full pb-4">{{ $user->firstName }} {{ $user->lastName }}</p>
                  <p class="w-full text-sm">Email:</p>
                  <p class="w-full pb-4">{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($user->email, 25, $end='...') }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-1/2">
                <div class="flex justify-start mb-3">
                  <div class="flex flex-wrap">
                  @foreach($roles as $role)
                    <label class="custom-label flex w-full py-1">
                      <div class="bg-gray-700 shadow w-6 h-6 p-1 flex justify-center items-center mr-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="roles[]" value="{{ $role->id }}" @if($user->roles->pluck('id')->contains($role->id)) checked @endif >
                        <svg class="hidden w-4 h-4 text-white pointer-events-none" viewBox="0 0 172 172"><g fill="none" stroke-width="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode:normal"><path d="M0 172V0h172v172z"/><path d="M145.433 37.933L64.5 118.8658 33.7337 88.0996l-10.134 10.1341L64.5 139.1341l91.067-91.067z" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="1"/></g></svg>
                      </div>
                      <span>{{$role->name}}</span>
                    </label>
                  @endforeach
                  </div>      
                </div>
              </div>                                        
            </div>

            <div class="flex justify-end">
              <button type="submit" class="px-4 bg-gray-600 p-2 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-indigo-400 mr-2">Update</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $user variable is never assigned when you hit the edit button, meaning it will show the last value from your iteration.

This is not possible using just PHP.
You need to use javascript to dynamically change the values of your modal form before showing it.

Answer (score -1):

You cant have an error in webpackmix.js.
In my case I change:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

for

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

all content in one line.